# Why are these NAs returned?

Tags: r, dataframe

Please excuse the poor question title... I could not think how to ask it in a better way.

I think the code speaks for itself, but just to labour the point, I 'searched' for a coded value in a data frame, replaced them all with NA, but on checking if they were gone I got a surprising result (to me).

```
> df[df==-999.25]
 [1] "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000"
 [6] "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000"
[11] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
[16] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
[21] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000"
[26] "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000"
[31] "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000"
[36] "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-999.25000000" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
[41] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
[46] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
[51] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
[56] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
[61] "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02" "-9.992500e+02"
> df[df==-999.25] <- NA
> df[df==-999.25]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[30] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[59] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I am confused by this. What is the reason for it? (I am also tired, perhaps I should have sat on this for a day or two). I checked the help for '<-' and '[', but learnt nothing (I could not follow all of it).

Comment: What's the surprising result?  What did you expect?

Comment: On second thought, I think I know.  `df==-999.25` has `NA`'s in it, and those get returned by `[`. See 8.1.12 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: So the question should be why are the NAs returned? Thanks @Aaron. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Awesome! My first downvote. Such a weird thing to receive, especially when there's no explanation. Guess I won't be learning anything from that then!

Comment: My condolences on the drive by downvoting, it's one of my pet peeves too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NA's are always returned when you use `==` if they are present because the result of comparing NA to whatever is NA which is returned by default. if you want them gone then you need to add `& !is.na(df)`

for example

```
test <- c(NA,5,3,2,34,"Bob")
test[test == "Bob"]
[1] NA    "Bob"
```

because

```
test == "Bob"
[1] NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `NA` to an object it means that you do not know what is inside that object, missing values, so logical statement and arithmetic calculation as * +  < == > can not be applied on the missing value and R reacts by returning `NA` for this cases:

```
a <- NA

a * 0
[1] NA

a/0
[1] NA

a<0
[1] NA

a == 0
[1] NA
```

Finally, I guess that you expected the result to be `False` instead of `NA` in `df[df==-999.25]`, but how R can make inference on your logical statement when R  have no idea about the Not Available or Missing Data